# Combine two Javascript Objects into one Object with same keys

Tags: javascript, object, javascript-objects, concatenation

I need help combining two objects with same keys into one object. I am getting these objects from an api request.

My first object:

```
var obj1 = {
RefinableString15: "Claims",
RefinableString16: "2123",
RefinableString17: "New York Cyberstate",
RefinableString19: "Global Property",
RefinableString20: "",
RefinableString21: "",
RefinableString22: "",
RefinableString23: "",
RefinableString24: "",
RefinableString25: ""
}
```

My second object:

```
var obj2 = {
RefinableString15: "",
RefinableString16: "",
RefinableString17: "",
RefinableString19: "",
RefinableString20: "Test",
RefinableString21: "Red",
RefinableString22: "Test",
RefinableString23: "Red",
RefinableString24: "Test",
RefinableString25: "Green"
}
```

I want it to look like this in the end:

```
{
RefinableString15: "Claims",
RefinableString16: "2123",
RefinableString17: "New York Cyberstate",
RefinableString19: "Global Property",
RefinableString20: "Test",
RefinableString21: "Red",
RefinableString22: "Test",
RefinableString23: "Red",
RefinableString24: "Test",
RefinableString25: "Green"
}
```

I have tried Object.assign, but it didn't work for my problem.

Comment: You need to `delete` the empty fields of the second object before using `assign()` or they will overwrite the first object's non-empty fields.

Comment: I can't, all properties are "read only property" so it wont let me delete. any other way with out using "Object.assign".

Comment: @SaadRH then there's something you're not telling us. *Typescript* has read-only properties (you didn't tag TS), and Javascript lets you create non-writable properties with `Object.defineProperty`, but that wouldn't apply to something you got from an API call. What's your real problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var obj1 = {
  RefinableString15: "Claims",
  RefinableString16: "2123",
  RefinableString17: "New York Cyberstate",
  RefinableString19: "Global Property",
  RefinableString20: "",
  RefinableString21: "",
  RefinableString22: "",
  RefinableString23: "",
  RefinableString24: "",
  RefinableString25: ""
}

var obj2 = {
  RefinableString15: "",
  RefinableString16: "",
  RefinableString17: "",
  RefinableString19: "",
  RefinableString20: "Test",
  RefinableString21: "Red",
  RefinableString22: "Test",
  RefinableString23: "Red",
  RefinableString24: "Test",
  RefinableString25: "Green"
}

function merge(object1, object2) {
  const keys = Object.keys(object1);
  return keys.reduce((result, item) => {
    result[item] = object1[item] || object2[item];
    return result;
  }, {})
}

console.log(merge(obj1, obj2))
```

Comment: What happens if neither value is falsey but they're different? What happens if the set of keys isn't exactly the same? What happens if the first value is falsey and the key doesn't exist in the second object? You'll get `undefined` instead of an empty string and now you've broken any code that relies on the type being string.

Comment: @JaredSmith as per the OP, the keys are always the same. As for what if neither key is falsey, it's up to the person called the function which one they want to give priority to

Comment: Fair enough. Have plus one.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this:

```js
var obj1 = 
    { RefinableString15: "Claims"
    , RefinableString16: "2123"
    , RefinableString17: "New York Cyberstate"
    , RefinableString19: "Global Property"
    , RefinableString20: ""
    , RefinableString21: ""
    , RefinableString22: ""
    , RefinableString23: ""
    , RefinableString24: ""
    , RefinableString25: ""
    } 
var obj2 = 
    { RefinableString15: ""
    , RefinableString16: ""
    , RefinableString17: ""
    , RefinableString19: ""
    , RefinableString20: "Test"
    , RefinableString21: "Red"
    , RefinableString22: "Test"
    , RefinableString23: "Red"
    , RefinableString24: "Test"
    , RefinableString25: "Green"
    } 

    
const cleanObj = o => Object.entries(o).reduce((a,[k,v])=>{if(v!='') a[k]=v;return a}, {}) 
     
var obj3 = { ...obj1, ...cleanObj(obj2)  }

console.log ( obj3 )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important;  top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to clean up empty properties and merge two objects. Something like that

```
  function clean(obj) {
            for (const propName in obj) {
                if (
                    obj[propName] === '' ||
                    obj[propName] === null ||
                    obj[propName] === undefined
                ) {
                    delete obj[propName];
                }
            }
            return obj;
        }
    const result = {...clean(obj1),...clean(obj2)};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `forEach` loop and build one object where values push only non empty strings.

```js
var obj1 = {
  RefinableString15: "Claims",
  RefinableString16: "2123",
  RefinableString17: "New York Cyberstate",
  RefinableString19: "Global Property",
  RefinableString20: "",
  RefinableString21: "",
  RefinableString22: "",
  RefinableString23: "",
  RefinableString24: "",
  RefinableString25: ""
};

var obj2 = {
  RefinableString15: "",
  RefinableString16: "",
  RefinableString17: "",
  RefinableString19: "",
  RefinableString20: "Test",
  RefinableString21: "Red",
  RefinableString22: "Test",
  RefinableString23: "Red",
  RefinableString24: "Test",
  RefinableString25: "Green"
};

const res = {};
Object.keys(obj1).forEach(key => (res[key] = obj1[key] || obj2[key]));

console.log(res);
```